# How to access a web API with HTTP POST and JSON

Tags: web-access, api

I want to get data using HTTPS from

```
POST https://developers.betfair.com/api.betfair.com/exchange/betting/json-rpc/v1 HTTP/1.1
```

using JSON

```
[{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "SportsAPING/v1.0/listEvents", "params": {"filter":{}}, "id": 1}]
```

I have to provide values for X-Application and X-Authentication ( which I have but are private for the account ).

I know that this can be done directly from Mathematica.

Which function should I use and where / how should I provide the URL, POST, X-Application, X-Authentication and JSON data.

Example code for a similar API would already be helpful, I guess.

Comment: I generally use [`URLFetch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLFetch.html) with the `"Headers"` and `"Body"` option.

Comment: @chuy - Ok. I did not know about all the options of URLFetch. Will look into that, I suppose that might work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick if you fill in the appropriate authentication headers:

```
url = "https://developers.betfair.com/api.betfair.com/exchange/betting/json-rpc/v1";
json = "[{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"SportsAPING/v1.0/listEvents\", \"params\":  {\"filter\":{}}, \"id\": 1}]";

URLFetch[url, {"StatusCode", "Headers", "Content"}, 
         "Body" -> json, 
         Method -> "POST", 
         "Headers" -> {"X-Application" -> "Hello", 
                       "X-Authentication" -> "World"}
]
```

Comment: Feels weird to use a function named Fetch to do a Post, I think they messed up the naming.