# How to use URLFetch for a https secure automated login?

Tags: web-access

UPDATE 9 March 2017:
I **added a bounty** to this question, I think it is a hard and challenging problem and can prove that Mathematica is capable of almost anything.

Sadly user1473011's answer does not work. I came back to this issue for many times, so far all my attempts to handle this from within Mathematica failed. Although I have a working solution in the form of a Java program I would rather have it done inside Mathematica.

With Mathematica 11.0.1 on Windows 10 I want to use URLFetch to do a so called 'Non-interactive/Bot login' at Betfair. The Betfair API manual gives this example in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests

payload = 'username=myusername&password=password'
headers = {'X-Application': 'SomeKey', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

resp = requests.post('https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/certlogin', data=payload, cert=('client-2048.crt', 'client-2048.key'), headers=headers)

if resp.status_code == 200:
  resp_json = resp.json()
  print resp_json['loginStatus']
  print resp_json['sessionToken']
else:
  print "Request failed."
```

'client-2048.crt' and 'client-2048.key' are files which I have generated with win-openssl and are stored on disk. I have a username and password.

There are also examples for C# and Java in the [API Manual](https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Interactive+Login+-+API+Endpoint)

I came as far the following URLFetch but I get a HTTP 405 return code, which was to be expected because I did not know how to handle the certification file, I generated earlier, basically the question is how to translate the python to URLfetch with an emphasis on the cert file.

```
URLFetch["https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/certlogin", {"StatusCode",    "Headers", "Content"}, "Headers" -> {"X-Application" -> "nilostep", "Accept" ->"application/json"}, "Parameters" -> {"Username" -> "myusername", "Password" -> "mypassword"}];
```

I have successfully used the API before but I copied a 'session token' for access which you can get only after manually logging in. Related question: [How to access a web API with HTTP POST and JSON](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105940/how-to-access-a-web-api-with-http-post-and-json)

(EDIT: Any example of a https secure login using certification keys using Mathematica will help.)

(EDIT-2: Might this help?: [Can anyone explain how to use Mathematica's OAuth package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23279/can-anyone-explain-how-to-use-mathematicas-oauth-package) ? )

Comment: No, typo. I'll correct it. Thanks @Kuba

Comment: You should remove the space before "https" in `URLFetch[" http`.

Comment: I am embarrassed but I can move on now. Thanks @rhermans

Comment: Basically the question is how to translate the python to urlfetch.

Comment: Presumably "session Token" is a cookie ...right? So have you tried using the "Cookies" and "StoreCookies" option?

Comment: Session token is a response from the server. I mean that is step 2, I suppose.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch - See EDIT-2 in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This api isn't accessible in the US, which makes it difficult to post a working code.

Try:

```
myCert = Import["path/to/my.crt"];

file = FileNameJoin[{
                     Replace["Location",PacletInformation["HTTPClient"]],
                     "SSL",
                     "cacert.pem"
                     }];

(*Append your certificate to the existing cacert.pem file*)
o = OpenAppend[file];
WriteString[o, "\n" <> myCert];
Close[o];

URLFetch[ "https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/certlogin",
    { "StatusCode", "Headers", "Content" },
    Method->"POST",
    "Headers" -> {
        "X-Application" -> "nilostep",
        "Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept" -> "application/json", 
        "Username" -> "myusername",
        "Password" -> "mypassword"
    }
]
```

Comment: There are other access points :
identitysso.betfair.com
identitysso.betfair.es
identitysso.betfair.it
identitysso.w-con.betfair.com
identitysso.betfaironline.eu

Comment: I have created files with the following exts: crt, csr, key, p12 and pem. In the workaround that I created ( see answer ) I use the file with p12 extension but this file requires an additional password. My point being which file should I use in "path/to/cert" ? I used the path to .pem and received the following result:
{400, {{"Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8"}, {"Content-Length",
    "82"}, {"Date", "Mon, 15 Feb 2016 19:49:52 GMT"}, {"Connection", 
   "close"}, {"Vary", 
   "Accept-Encoding"}}, \
"<html><head><title></title></head><body><h1>HTTP Error Code \
400</h1></body></html>"}

Comment: Why haven't you added 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ? See Python example.

Answer (score 3):

#### On SSL and cert files

So this seems to fundamentally be a question of doing SSL certification. Going from [here](http://members.wolfram.com/meng/pages/computing/installing_and_configuring/installing_and_configuring_mathematica/#.WMRi7hIrLdR) there's some discussion of adding SSL certificates in a standard location. Here's a way to find your equivalent of that file:

```
$CAFile =
  First@FileNames["*.pem", $InstallationDirectory, \[Infinity]];
```

Mine lives here:

```
FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", 
  "CURLLink", "SSL", "cacert.pem"}
```

And as `URLRead` calls `URLFetch`, which in turn calls the `CURLLink` system I think this is the right place to append my credentials.

Here's a *wholly untested* way to do this (as I have no .pem files to test it with) without copying it in by hand:

```
CAAppend[cert_String?(Not@*FileExistsQ)] :=

  If[Not@StringContainsQ[Import[$CAFile, "Text"], cert],
   CopyFile[$CAFile,
    FileNameJoin@{DirectoryName@$CAFile,
      FileBaseName@$CAFile <> "_backup." <> FileExtension@$CAFile
      }];
   With[{append = OpenAppend[$CAFile]},
    WriteString[append, cert];
    Close@append;
    ]
   ];
CAAppend[cert_String?FileExistsQ] :=
  CAAppend@Import[cert, "Text"];
```

Obviously the best way would be to find some way to pass the necessary SSL cert data in the headers of an http request, but that'll take more research.

#### Original posting

Since you mention you're on 11. have you tried formatting an `HTTPRequest` instead? I've had success using it to get an application-only access token off of Twitter. Basically I followed [their guide](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) and ended up with this:

```
HTTPRequest[
  <|
   "Scheme" -> "https",
   "Domain" -> "api.twitter.com",
   "Path" -> {"oauth2", "token"}
   |>,
  <|
   "Host" -> "api.twitter.com",
   "Body" ->
    {"grant_type" -> "client_credentials"},
   "UserAgent" ->
    $consumerName,
   "Headers" -> {
     "Authorization" ->
      "Basic " <> $bearerToken
     }
   |>
  ] // Import
```

then translating that over to the template you had I ran this (note that when you have your real `$cert` files you should uncomment `File/@` in `$cert`.

```
$cert =
  (*File/@*){"client-2048.crt", "client-2048.key"};
$username =
  "myusername";
$password =
  "mypassword";
$application =
  "SomeKey";
HTTPRequest[
  <|
   "Scheme" -> "https",
   "Domain" -> "identitysso.w-con.betfair.com",
   "Path" -> {"api", "certlogin"}
   |>,
  <|
   "Headers" -> {
     "X-Application" ->
      $application
     },
   "Body" -> {
     "username" ->
      $username,
     "password" ->
      $password,
     "cert" ->
      $cert
     }
   |>
  ] // Import[#, "JSON"] &
```

Executing that returns:

```
{"loginStatus" -> "ACCOUNT_ALREADY_LOCKED"}
```

Which tells me that something is happening. Try dropping in your credentials and see what happens.

Comment: I received, the
{"loginStatus" -> "CERT_AUTH_REQUIRED"}
message.

My $cert = {"C:\\OpenSSL-Win32\\client-2048.crt", 
  "C:\\OpenSSL-Win32\\client-2048.key"} these files exist in my dir.

I have also tried it with $cert = {"C:\\OpenSSL-Win32\\client-2048.p12"}, this is the file I use in my Java program. No success either.

I also tried $cert = "C:\\OpenSSL-Win32\\client-2048.p12" with no success.

Comment: I would try mapping `File` over those as is shown in the [`HTTPRequest` docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HTTPRequest.html).

Comment: I thought that was a comment. Will try now.

Comment: I had it commented out because `HTTPRequest` whined at me, thinking I was trying to send files that didn't exist. If you look under the `"Body"` part of Details and Options it has something on using `File` to send files.

Comment: OK.
Message[Import::fmterr, "JSON"]; Return[$Failed]
Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as JSON format.

If I leave out the "JSON" from the Import then I get
HTTP Error Code 400

Comment: 400 means "malformed request". Give me a moment to see what could be going wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55191/discussion-between-mb1965-and-nilo-de-roock).

Comment: I read Step 2 from the Twitter guide, that is exactly what I am doing, I am expecting a TOKEN, only in my case from Betfair.

Comment: So they want me to move this to a chat (so I started one) but that's why I thought this would be similar. I got twitter to work. It's all a question of how where the cert goes / how it's encoded I think.

Comment: Betfair documentation for bot login is here.
http://docs.developer.betfair.com/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Non-Interactive+%28bot%29+login

Comment: Reading the [docs for the python requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/) that `cert` keyword is actually a special SSL specifier so the question is really about how we configure SSL in a `HTTPRequest`. It's worth trying to configure your .pem file rather than the cert key tuple as a start. I'll look into that more.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is a working workaround.

```
Needs["JLink`"]
BOTA = "D:\\Dropbox\\DATA\\MyJavaProjects\\bota\\out\\artifacts\\bota_jar\\bota.jar";
ReinstallJava[CommandLine -> "C:\\Progra~1\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_45\\jre\\bin\\java", ClassPath -> BOTA];
conn = JavaNew["org.nilostep.bota.HttpClientSSO"]
conn@getSessionKey[]
```

bota.jar contains the class HttpClientSSO as described in the API manual ( see question ) with an additional method that returns the sessionkey as a string.

Classpath is the path to bota.jar

getSessionKey() returns a String and is a new method in HttpClientSSO

The above should be possible with just URLFetch though.